# Explanation of this JavaScript Code

Tags: javascript

I'm not too good on the whole JavaScript (I can do some basic validations) but this isn't my zone

I've got a piece of code below that I'm trying to understand what it does, I can read any code and understand a few parts, but this just stumped me.

Here:

```
function tm_search_click() {
    if (document.getElementById('tm').value == 'Enter your trademark') {
        document.getElementById('tm').style.backgroundColor = '#fcc';
        return false;
    } else {
        window.location = '?tm=' + escape(document.getElementById('tm').value);
        return true;
    }
}
function qs(a) {
    a = a.replace(/[[]/, "\[").replace(/[]]/, "\]");
    var b = "[\?&]" + a + "=([^&#]*)";
    var c = new RegExp(b);
    var d = c.exec(window.location.href);
    return d == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(d[1]).replace(/+/g, " ")
}
if (qs("tm") != "") {
    tm_trademark = document.getElementById("tm").value = unescape(qs("tm"));
    tm_partner = "migu2008";
    tm_frame_width = 630;
    tm_frame_height = "auto";
    tm_trademark_country_code = "GB";
    tm_css_url = "http://remarqueble.com/api/theme/search_corporate.css";
    document.getElementById("tmLoading").style.display = "block";
    tm_on_search_result = function () {
        document.getElementById("tmLoading").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("tmLoaded").style.display = "block"
    }
} else {
    tm_search_method = "none"
}
```

That is all of it without the `<script>` tags.

Could I also edit this code so that it searches are made based on what option the user inputs?

Comment: Not easy to say without seeing the DOM.

Comment: Which part isn't understood? Have you broken it down piece-by-piece?

Comment: I have tried to break it down, and what do you mean by the DOM @LightnessRacesinOrbit?

Comment: @user1191118: The [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) tree is the tree of nodes that you get when the page's HTML source is parsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it works like this (assuming that this is in  tags inside html page)

1. Page loads.
2. The script checks if URL has 'tm' parameter. If it has, then it sets bunch of tm_.. parameters and callback function. I don't know how they are used.
3. User clicks something that triggers the tm_search_click
4. Script sets new URL for the page and browser starts loading that
5. Goto step 1.

Comment: Thanks very much - I see it clear now, I wonder how I'm going to include a variable in this :/

Comment: Pretty hard to say without seeing the HTML, but I think it already searches value that was written in 'tm' field. It's probably '<input id="tm" ..>' in the HTML.

Comment: aha! Now I'm getting somewhere! Thank you!

Comment: <div style="position: absolute; left: 181; top: 1068; width: 529; height: 300; z-index: 100; overflow: hidden; background-color: ffffff;"> 
           <input id="tm" name="tm" onclick="if(this.value=='Enter your trademark') this.value='';" type="text" value="Enter your trademark"> 
           <input onclick="tm_search_click();" type="button" value="Search">
           <div id="tmLoading" style="display:none"> Processing search results...<br></div>  What I'm trying to do is have it search  with the value of this menu, suggestions?

Comment: menu: <html>
            <body>
              <select>
                 <option>Class</option>
                 <option value="Computers">1. Computers</option>
                 <option value="Medicinal">2. Medicinal</option>
                 <option value="Textiles">3. Textiles</option>
              </select>
            </body>
          </html>